# Google sheet showing #VALUE! error for non-formula cell

Tags: google-sheets

I received a Google Sheet where cells with text values in it (A, B), are appearing as #VALUE! The thing is, the cell IS NOT a formula. It contains only text.

I tried copy/paste special - only values. It works if I paste in another column but if I try to paste to the same column, it does not work.

Is there a way to set the column format so the values are shown. What intrigues me is that there is no formula for this error to appear.

Bellow is a snapshot. Cell A1 contains the letter **B** but the sheet show **#VALOR!**, which is the value error in Portuguese.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution seconds after posting the question.

I had to set the cell format to automatic. The problem is that in the Portuguese version of google sheets, the menu item for the automatic format is nested inside the 'Number' option. To that threw me for a while.

[image]